# Understanding Swift Deinitializers

Tags: swift, deinit

Swift deinitializer is not updating the valueone and valuetwo, i am getting zero as the answer when i am printing mainTotal.sum, it should update the value and print the answer as 95

```
struct mainTotal{
   static var valueone :Int = 0
   static var valuetwo :Int = 0
   static var sum :Int {
        get {
            return valueone + valuetwo
        }
    }
}

class Total{
    var valueone :Int = 10
    var valuetwo :Int = 10
    var sum :Int {
        get {
            return valueone + valuetwo
        }
    }
    func printsum(valueone:Int,valuetwo:Int){
        self.valueone += valueone
        self.valuetwo += valuetwo
    }
    deinit {
       mainTotal.valueone += valueone
       mainTotal.valuetwo += valuetwo

    }
}

var total = Total()
total.printsum(valueone: 10,valuetwo: 15)
var total1 = Total()
total1.printsum(valueone: 10,valuetwo: 20)
print(mainTotal.sum)
print(total.sum)
```

Comment: You `total` `deinit` will be called after you check `mainTotal.sum`, because `total` is referenced after `mainTotal.sum`.

Comment: Why do you expect the `deinit` to be called before your print statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`deinit` of `Total` is not getting called and that's why the values of `mainTotal` are not getting updated.

To call `deinit` of `Total`, you need to deallocate the `total` object manually.

Try this:

```
var total : Total? = Total()
total?.printsum(valueone: 10,valuetwo: 15)
print(total!.sum)
total = nil
print(mainTotal.sum)
```